# FastAPI + jinja2 + websockets + TemplateResponse

Tags: jinja2, fastapi

Изучаю FastAPI + jinja2. Не работает TemplateResponse с websockets. Нет объекта request.

```
@app.get("/")
async def get_init(request: Request):
    ...
    ...
    Тут работает
    return templates.TemplateResponse(name_template, {"request": request})


@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    ...
    ...
    Тут НЕ работает
    return templates.TemplateResponse(name_template, {"request": request})
```

Comment: Что именно не работает? Вы эндпоинт вебсокета браузером пытаетесь открыть, я так понимаю?

Comment: Какой вообще смысл использовать TemplateResponse в вебсокете? Не очень понятно, что вы вообще пытаетесь сделать

Comment: Есть базовый шаблон и встраиваемые (изменяемые) блоки. Хочу чтобы шаблоны отдавала функция. Пока реализовано просто через файлопен. На фронтэнде htmx но это думаю не важно. Не знаю как еще объяснить ). Сервер должен отдать файл html а не json данные что-то типа SSR

Comment: Думаю есть такой путь - хранение шаблонов в БД а не в файлах, тогда будет другая реализация без темплейте респонсе

Comment: Вебсокеты нужны для непрерывного обмена информацией (например, в виде json) между фронтом (клиентом) и бэкэндом. Шаблоны для вебсокетов использовать не имеет смысла.

Comment: Да, согласен, перемудрил, гонять шаблоны по вебсокетам неправильно, переделал на get, post